# understanding parameters in callbacks and recursion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, higher-order-functions

I am currently reading Eloquent JavaScript by Marijn Haverbeke and there is a piece of code that I want someone to explain for me. Consider the following commented code:

```js
class Network {
   constructor() {
 // irrelevent code except the following line
 this.types = Object.create(null)
}

   defineRequestType(name, handler) {
        this.types[name] = handler
      }
}

// when we call the defineRequestType method in another module.


defineRequestType("note", (nest, content, source, done) => {
    // this is the callback I am referring to. (See below)
    console.log(`${nest.name} received note: ${content}`);  
    done(); 
  });

// last but not least, the send method

send(to, type, message, callback) {
        let toNode = this[$network].nodes[to]
        let handler = this[$network].types[type] // this is important. we're referring to the function's callback that we just called, and this callback is our handler
        if (!handler) // not important
          return callback(new Error("Unknown request type " + type))
        if (Math.random() > 0.03) setTimeout(() => {
          try {
                 /*
                    When we call the send method, the part that I don't understand is that we passed 'done()' as a callback to the handler. 
                    However, as you can see in the previous function call, done() does not take any arguments. 
                    Yet, the handler expects the callback of the handler to have 2 arguments 'error' and 'response'. How is this possible?
                 */
            handler(toNode, ser(message), this.name, (error, response) => {
              setTimeout(() => callback(error, ser(response)), 10)
            })
          } catch(e) {
            callback(e)
          }
        }, 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
      }
```

In case you are interested in reading the source code, please take a look at the this link were you will find the above functions and more (quite sophisticated) functions. Please click on crow tech and Chapter 11 to see the full code. (In case requested).

[Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#11)

Comment: This code is a little tricky to follow, but maybe the source of confusion is that you don't _have_ to call Javascript functions with the number of arguments they define. The Javascript runtime allows you to call them with more or fewer arguments, and it's up to the function body to handle that. See also [the arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). It could just be a bug/typo where they forgot to call with args